# Python v2 convert scientific notation from string to float - values are changing

Tags: python, string, floating-point, scientific-notation

I'm using Python 2.7.11 and I have a text file with x,y,z values that represent values from a raster (lon, lat, value).

I'm trying to import this file into a numpy array so I can continue processing it with an existing set of python code, however I'm getting issues when converting from string to scientific notation.

```
x,y,z = [], [], []
f = open(xyz_file, 'r')

for l in f:
    row = l.split()
    x.append(row[0])
    y.append(row[1])
    z.append(row[2])
```

This results in the z list containing strings in scientific notation:

```
['8.23984e+05',
 '3.85186e-34',
 '2.31061e+06',
 '0.00000e+00',
 '9.86076e-32',
 '0.00000e+00', etc.
```

The min-max values on this list are:

```
-1.00000e+00
nan
```

If I create the array, I get an error:

```
A = np.array((x, y, z), dtype=float)

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-3e00a73369e4> in <module>()
----> 1 A = np.array((x, y, z))

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence
```

I thought there may be a problem with the scientific notation being strings, so I converted them:

```
z3 = []
rows = len(z)
for i in range(0, rows):
    val = float(z[i])
    z3.append(val)
```

The min-max values on this list are now, which are different from above:

```
-3.40281e+38
3.40282e+38
```

I checked if removing the 'nan' values would help and initially the min-max values were:

```
z2 = [x for x in z if str(x) != 'nan']

-1.00000e+00
9.99999e-34
```

When I then convert this list to float, I get the same wrong min-max values:

```
z4 = []
rows2 = len(z2)
for i in range(0, rows2):
    val = float(z2[i])
    z4.append(val)

-3.40281e+38
3.40282e+38
```

Can anyone explain why the values are changing when I convert from string to float?

Comment: If you provide example values that show this behaviour, it will be easier to help you.

Comment: if max shows as `9.99999e-34`, you should perhaps worry about the quality of your max evaluation. Running max over a list of strings will not magically sort them according to the numeric value of the string representations; could you expose how you compute those min/max?